# Can I hide one of my siamese twins heads in public?

Tags: creature-design, clothing

The Siamese twin character is actually a product of a mad scientist sewing two halves of separate female bodies together and keeping both heads.

Their body will essentially look like one body apart from widening up towards the shoulders to fit the two heads with a little space between both necks and heads.

Ignoring the realities that this wouldn't be likely possible in the real world how can I at times get away with them going out in public maybe taking turns to be in control with the other head quietly hides somehow?

As they are female there may be more options for extravagant clothing and head garments or if theres another options that can allow this character to hide the second head for short moments out in public other than maybe turning to the side or other obscuring view points.

Edit, I just thought a strange haircut could be an option, the hiding one pushing the hair over their face as the other combs some of theres over the hidden head but I am not sold on this idea yet.

Comment: About how impossible it is... https://images.app.goo.gl/4DdEj81ZwtSorKy78

Comment: yep they are a famous twin set, I meant sowing two separate bodies together

Comment: You'd have to match them genetically as if you were transplanting an organ, then give them immunosuppressants (god thats annoying to spell) for the rest of their lives. I think it is likely you would have to destroy the immune system of one of the persons you combine as even with immunosuppressants a combined immune system will likely annihilate each other. Even with those precautions the chance of rejection and infection with death as the outcome is very large. The human centipede would likely have ended with rejections freeing the "patients"

Comment: This query is too story based.  Now that it has been closed, this is your opportunity to either edit this or scrap it and begin with a new, non-story based query.  What we mean by story based is quite simply that you are asking about plot points.  WB answers queries about how the fictional world itself functions, not how to cobble together a story.  If you'd like to reword this question so it focuses on worldbuilding, I for one would be happy to vote to reopen!

Comment: @elemtilas, understood, I think im happy with one of the answers which will now accept as the best suggestion, I meant it as is there known specific clothing garments from real life or fiction but that probably isn't a question for world building.

Comment: probably the easiest solution is a fake "package",a hollow box or bag balanced on that "shoulder".  Heads are bulky, I don't think hats, scarves, or hair would work to hide something like that.  It would be unusual to carry a package on one's shoulder *all* the time, but less so than carrying a second head, and some people do have such habitual quirks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one way: Hide it in plain sight. With the right makeup and clothing, you can make it look like a costume. This will admittingly  work best with some sort of event (maybe a Halloween party or season)
The main idea is to convince people that since it's so obvious, it must be fake. It's obviously a costume right? Two headed people don't exist.

Hiding in plain sight.

Comment: I get where your going but I cant have her going shopping or trying to be sexy in a bar with a prop head all the time

Comment: Or you could go the *Young Frankenstein* way: What hump?

Comment: ,that's an idea, I was thinking trying to duck the head to hide in cleavage but that wouldn't work, tucked behind could work, a hump can have all sorts of things covering it, nice idea thanks.

Comment: accepting this answer for the later hump suggestion.

Answer (score 16):

Zaphod, president of the Galaxy, once hid his second head by putting a cage over it and pretending it held a talking bird.

In the movie, he also hides it in his [coat collar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZO9oKNKGNo).

Comment: Ha! that's hillarious

Comment: +1 for mentioning one of the great SF books / movies of all time!

Answer (score 1):

Hair cuts, scarves, large hats, you could fun with a cloak with a hood. If there is magic, there could be some way o magically hiding the other head.

At the same time though, it may be fun to just freak everyone out by walking around with two heads.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a modern world, how about a little almost-technomancy? I assume if there’s a mad scientist capable of sewing two heads onto a single body, there could be a second skilled mad scientist/tech whiz who would be up for the fun of hiding two heads in plain sight. There’s two science-related solutions I can think of off the top of my head.

1) The second head can be **cloaked by a cloaking device**. This one would be very hard to achieve with modern-day technologies, but perhaps in the future it wouldn’t be nearly as difficult. Even in the modern day we have some more limited prototypes capable of certain ‘stealth’ effects (see [here](https://globalnews.ca/news/4302166/invisibility-cloak-technology/)). Whatever cloaking device you use, you could hang a lampshade (not literal) on it by explaining any technical glitches that happen with it on makeup, special effects, or covering it with clothing. The device would probably work very well in dark places, like clubs or some bars. It would also make the story more entertaining because the flaws of the device itself affects how your character interacts with her world, eg. hiding in shadows, an occasional baddie seeing through the disguise and wiping his eyes in confusion after seeing it back to normal, etc.

2) We make the second head **[somebody else’s problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_else%27s_problem)**. This refers to a device from the book series *Hitchhiker’s Guide to the Galaxy*, where a Somebody Else’s Problem field is generated to make people ignore whatever is under it, as if it’s ‘somebody else’s problem’. This one is more of a hard sell; essentially there would be some kind of hypnotic device that induces others not to pay attention to the second head. You could again use makeup, clothes, etc to make the other head even more attention-worthy, especially if it were a head-turner. This one could also make for fun in the story, as glitches can make things more adventurous, although if the device were glitch free enough it could also allow the character to be more carefree in their interactions. It might even be good enough that people touching the second head would have no idea. (It’s also, in my opinion, the coolest device in the Hitchhiker series).

Edit: 2.a) This one is also out there, but on the subject of clothing, perhaps as your character is out in a crowd and needs to stay out of attention, a piece of clothing with some [optical illusion](https://www.livescience.com/23094-spiral-circle-illusion-explained.html) patterns would be nice. It could let your characters head seem smaller, or, even better, give a severe headache to anyone who focused their gaze on it, enough to let them overlook the ‘slightly larger’ head of your character.